# jquery: Add code to click event

Tags: jquery

I want to keep a reference of the button click function, do my stuff, then run the original click function.

I know usually I can do such things in document.ready, e.g:

```
    var originalOnClick = $("#myBtn").click;
    $("#myBtn").click = function() {
      // do my staff here, and only then call the original:
      originalOnClick();
    }
```

(please correct this code if it is wrong!)

but, I have a special case. in my page onLoad function, there are asynchronous ajax calls. so functions called on document.ready are actually called before the ajax code was finished.

Is there a way to change the click event when calling click() or onclick() ? I mean, is there an event that is called immediatly before\after the click event?

or that I must ask the user to click a (I can see that this page is loaded) button, and only then I can do my staff ?

EDIT 1: The ajax code is in an included script. I cannot change it.

EDIT 2: Possible solution: hide the original button, but use its event:

HTML:

```
 <div class="object1" style="display: none;" >original button.</div>
 <div class="object2">my button.</div>
```

JS:

```
function doMyStuff() {
    alert(' doMyStuff .');
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.object1').click(function(){
     alert('original staff. ');        
  });  // actually, this is just a test code. In my project, I cannot edit this function

  $('.object2').click(function() {
   doMyStuff();
    $('.object1').click();      
  });
});
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to redefine the `click` *method* of *one particular element*? Replacing the method will only affect that specific jQuery object. When you later on retrieve the same element with `$("#myBtn")`, it will return a *new* jQuery object *without* your previous changes. Please elaborate more about what you're intending to do with this, so we can get a better understanding and suggest better alternatives.

Comment: this page is getting\setting values of hardware. The original click event sends new values to the hardware. I want to add a message for the user "your values are being committed".

Comment: Are those values being sent in another event handler being bound to `click`? Or are those values coming from a `<form>` being submitted by clicking on an `<input type="submit">`?

Comment: on window.onLoad() , ajax gets the values, and on button.click(), ajax sets the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a click event that then removes itself as an event handler and then creates a new event handler:

```
function doNormalStuffWithClick() {
}

//First click
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
    // switch off this event handler
    $(this).off('click');
    // do stuff with first click
    // ....
    doNormalStuffWithClick();

    // Set up handler for subsequent clicks
    $("#myBtn").click(function() {
      doNormalStuffWithClick();
    });
}
```

Comment: `$(this).off('click')` will remove *all* bound event handlers. You probably only want this single event handler to be removed, in which case you need to name it or store it in a variable first and call `$(this).off('click', myHandler)`.

Comment: will the following work? it looks recursive, and what happens when it is called again - 

var originalOnClick = NULL;

function doMyStuff() {
  myStuff();
  if (originalOnClick) 
    originalOnClick(); 
}

//First click
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
    originalOnClick = $("#myBtn").click; // will it save the original ?
    $(this).off('click');
    doMyStuff();
    
    // what happens when this function is called the second time ?!
}

Comment: I found another solution, use myButton, which calls originalButton.click()

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to prevent a user from clicking your button before the ajax functions have completed. There are several ways to do this. The easiest way looks like this:

```
var ajaxCount = 0;

$.ajax('some/url', function(res){
    ajaxCount++
    // code here
});

$.ajax('some/url', function(res){
    ajaxCount++
    // code here
});

$('#myBtn').click(function(e){
    if(ajaxCount != 2) return false;

    // code here
});
```

In this form, you're simply checking to make sure both ajax functions have fired.

Comment: Assuming that this is indeed what the OP wants to achieve, there's a much easier way to do this using AJAX promises and [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Answer (score 0):

If binding code before your AJAX requests are done is an issue, you can call it on `ajaxSuccess`:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

If you want to do something after all AJAX requests are finished, you can check variables that you can set when each request begins. You can even try using `ajaxStart` to change number of current requests and later check it in `ajaxSuccess`

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    // do something
});
```